# Linux Mint, Screen is off after 1 second

Tags: linux-mint, kde

Linuxmint has decided to make my screen sleep after 1 second of me not using it.

How do I stop this timer?

Please Help

Using Linux Mint, with KDE.

Comment: "xset s off" "xset -dpms" "xset s noblank" did the trick

Comment: problem came back again, not sure what is doing this (though the commands DO help), help ?

Comment: commands no longer work, screens go off after 1 second of inactivity, something must be triggering xset (?)